# how do I allow a google app engine node js script to call cross domain?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am new to GAE / NODEJS. There is plenty of advice to enable calls hosted by GAE to be called cross domain, but I am having trouble getting my node js app to call another domains API. Is there something I need to do to get GAE to allow cross domain calls? My code is:

```
app.get('/listProducts', (req, res) => {
    request.get('https://[cross domain]/api/2.0/products', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
}).auth(null, null, true, '[key goes here]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allow configuring your app.yaml file or setting in your http header.
Here the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref) (looking for **CORS Support** )

Follow the example:

> You could have a game app **mygame.appspot.com** that accesses assets
>   hosted by **myassets.appspot.com**. However, if mygame attempts to
>   make a JavaScript XMLHttpRequest to myassets, it will not succeed
>   unless the handler for myassets returns an
>   **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**: response header containing the value
>   http://mygame.appspot.com.

Here is how you would make your static file handler return that required response header value:

```
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mygame.appspot.com
  # ...
```

Note: if you wanted to allow everyone to access your assets, you could use the wildcard '*', instead of http://mygame.appspot.com.

Comment: I believe the app.yaml change described above is for allowing OTHER sites (in other domains) to call into service calls hosted by the app. My question relates to the ability for my app to call other sites in other domains.

Comment: I not sure - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0):

was doing newbie - i should have returned a response code, eg response.status(200).send("ok").end();